# Deleting duplicate rows

Tags: sqlite

I am learning `SQLite` and constructed a line which I thought would delete dups but it deletes all rows instead.

```
DELETE from tablename WHERE rowid not in (SELECT distinct(timestamp) from tablename);
```

I expected this to delete rows with a duplicate (leaving one). I know I can simply create a new table with the distinct rows, but why does what I have done not work? Thanks

Comment: Please post the table structure for `tablename` and also add sample data.  Showing sample input and the expected output would be best.

Answer (score 2):

If `timestamp` is a column in the table and this is what you want to compare so to delete duplicates then do this:

```
delete from tablename 
where exists (
  select 1 from tablename t
  where t.rowid < tablename.rowid and t.timestamp = tablename.timestamp
)
```

Comment: You are comparing rowid which is an integer number to a column like timestamp which is totally unrelated.

Comment: Because all the comparisons fail, NOT IN returns TRUE and all the rows are deleted.

Answer (score 2):

With recent versions of sqlite, the following is an alternative:

```
DELETE FROM tablename
WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid
                FROM (SELECT rowid, row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY timestamp) AS rownum
                      FROM tablename)
                WHERE rownum >= 2);
```

Answer (score 1):

> why does what I have done not work?

Consider the WHERE condition:

```
rowid not in (SELECT distinct(timestamp) from tablename)
```

The simple answer is that you are not comparing data in the same columns, nor are they columns with the same type of data.  `rowid` is an automatically-incremented integer column and I assume that `timestamp` column is either a numeric or string column containing time values, or perhaps custom-generated sequential numeric values.  Because `rowid` likely *never matches* a value in `timestamp`, then the `NOT IN` operation will *always return true*.  Thus each row of the table will be deleted.

SQL is rather explicit and so there are no hidden/mysterious column comparisons.  It will not automatically compare the rowid's from one query with another.  Notice that the various alternative statements **do something to distinguish rows with duplicate key values** (`timestamp` in your case), either by direct comparison between main query and subquery, or using windowing functions to uniquely label rows with duplicate values, etc.

Just for kicks, here's another alternative that uses `NOT IN` like your original code.

```
DELETE FROM tablename 
WHERE rowid NOT IN (
  SELECT max(t.rowid) FROM tablename t
  GROUP BY t.timestamp )
```

First notice that this is comparing `rowid` with `max(t.rowid)`, values which derive from the same column.

Because the subquery groups on `t.timestamp`, the aggregate function `max()` will return the greatest/last `t.rowid` separately for each set of rows with the same `t.timestamp` value.  The resultant list will exclude `t.rowid` values that are less than the maximum.  Thus, the `NOT IN` operation will not find those lesser values and will return `true` so they will be deleted.

It also uses basic SQL (no window functions... the OVER keyword).  It will likely *be more efficient* than the alternative that references the outer query from the subquery, because this statement can execute the subquery just once and then use an efficient index to match individual records... it doesn't need to rerun the query for each row.  For that matter, it should also be more efficient than the windowing function, because the window partition essentially "groups" on the partitioned columns, but must then execute the windowing function for each row, an extra step not present in the basic aggregate query.  Efficiency is not always critical, but something important to consider.

---

By the way, the distinct keyword is not a function and does not need/accept parenthesis.  It is a directive that applies to the entire select statement.  The subquery is being interpreted as

```
SELECT DISTINCT (timestamp) FROM tablename
```

where DISTINCT is interpreted in isolation and the parenthesis are interpreted as a separate expression.

---

### Update

These two queries will return the same data:

```
SELECT DISTINCT timestamp FROM tablename;
SELECT timestamp FROM tablename GROUP BY timestamp;
```

Both results eliminate duplicate rows from the output by showing only unique/distinct values, but neither has a "handle" (other data column) which indicates which rows to keep and which rows to eliminate.  In other words, these queries return distinct values, but the results loose all relationship to the source rows and so have no use in specifying which source rows to delete (or keep).  To understand better, you should run subqueries separately to inspect what they return so that you can understand and verify what data you're working with.

To make those queries useful, we need to **do something to distinguish rows with duplicate key values**.  The rows need a "handle"--some other key value to select for either deleting or keeping those rows. Try this...

```
SELECT DISTINCT rowid, timestamp FROM tablename;
```

But that won't work, because it applies the DISTINCT keyword to ALL returned columns, but since rowid is already unique it will necessarily output each row separately and so there is no use to the query.

```
SELECT max(rowid), timestamp FROM tablename GROUP BY timestamp;
```

That query preserves the unique grouping, but provides *just one* rowid per timestamp as the "handle" to include/exclude for deletion.

Comment: Thanks for the further clarification. I realize that I needed an id for the rows to be deleted but (mistakenly) thought that I could get the rowids of the rows to be deleted by adding the NOT IN to the distinct modifier as in DELETE from tablename WHERE rowid not in SELECT distinct timestamp  from tablename; nut that is not how the NOT IN works

Comment: Yes, but I still perceive a possible misunderstanding of how SQL queries work.  Not only is that not how `NOT IN` works, but that is not how any SQL query works.  As I described in the answer, SQL is explicit and returns data sets *precisely* as defined.  A subquery only returns columns that are *explicitly specified* in the query.  There never could have been any automatic matchup between the main query's `rowid`  and the subquery's source rows because there is no automatic "link"/relationship that is kept even if from the same table... even if logically there is one that you can identify.

Answer (score 0):

**try this**

```
DELETE liens from liens where 
id in 
( SELECT * FROM (SELECT min(id) FROM liens group by lkey having count(*) > 1 ) AS c)
```

you can do this many times